# Can't compile on std::min_element's return

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<double, double> A;

    const auto it = std::min_element(A.begin(), A.end(),
                                [](decltype(A)::value_type& l, decltype(A)::value_type& r) -> bool { return l.second < r.second; });

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

I wish to compute the minimum in the map.

This code failed to compile. I thought the way to use `std::min_element`'s returned iterator is by referencing it. No?

The error message on the `std::cout` line is "invalid operands to binary expression".

Comment: In your case if you constructed the map with the keys as your values and values as your keys, the minimum value would just be `*A.begin()` since `std::map` stores its elements in sorted order.

Comment: Using `double` as key for `std::map` is usually not a good idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::map::iterator::value_type` (ie. the type of `*it`) is `std::pair<const double,double>`, and there is no standard overload of `operator<<(std::ostream &, std::pair<const double,double>)`.

You could either define one, or do something like `std::cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 4):

The element type of `std::map` is a `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`.  `*it` will give you a reference to that.  There is no output output operator defined for `std::pair` so the code fails to compile.

You will either have to add an overload for it like

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<const double, double>& e)
{
    return os << "{" << e.first << ", " << e.second << "}\n";
}
```

or just print what you want like

```
std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";
```